# Update Record Failed

Tags: vb.net

I'm having trouble updating my records. I don't know what seems to be the problem. After clicking update no error seems to be appearing. Here is my code.

```
    conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Charles\Documents\Database1.accdb"
    Dim cmd As String
    cmd = "UPDATE Employee SET EmployeeName = @eName, SSS = @SSS, TIN = @TIN, ED = @ED, Salary = @Salary WHERE EmployeeName = @eName"
    Dim cmdUpdate As New OleDbCommand(cmd, conn)

    enableTxtBox()
    If btnEdit.Text = "Edit" Then
        btnEdit.Text = "Update"
    Else
        btnEdit.Text = "Edit"

        Try
            conn.Open()
            cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eName", txtName.Text)
            cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SSS", txtSSS.Text)
            cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TIN", txtTIN.Text)
            cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ED", dtpED)
            cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Salary", txtSalary.Text)
            cmdUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery()

            fillListView()
            clearAll()
            disableTxtBox()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
        conn.Close()
    End If
```

Comment: You're saying that the `UPDATE` failed, yet you claim that no error is reported anywhere. So how do you know that it failed?

Comment: sorry, i was on vacation last weekend so i wasn't able to reply... as you can see i tried to catch if any errors will occur.. "BUT" upon editing a certain record, that record doesn't seem to be updating... but no errors are showing so i really don't know what code im missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ED", dtpED)
> ```

Assuming that `dtpED` is a `DateTimePicker` control, you probably want to set that parameter to `dtpED.Value` (i.e. the date selected in the control), not to the `dtpED` control itself:

```
cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ED", dtpED.Value)
                                             '^^^^^^'
```

By the way, I am assuming here that the `cmdUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery()` statement is actually reached and executed. That is not clear from your answer, due to the conditional check of `btnEdit.Text`. (If that button is labelled *Edit*, you will have to run your code twice to get to the command execution code, because once you're inside the `Then` clause, the `Else` clause will always be skipped, even if you change `btnEdit.Text`, which was part of the `If` condition.)